# Automate install of SQL Server 2005 Express Service Packs

Tags: windows-server-2003, automated-install, sql-server-2005, service-pack

Is it possible to perform an unnattended install of service packs (SP4 is the latest) on SQL Server 2005 Express?

The only way I have found is to download the SQLEXPR32.EXE containing SP4 and run it manually for each of my instances which need it. This takes ages, but I can't get any of the command line options to work.

I do have a SQL Server 2005 (not Express) instance on the server as well, but I can download and apply the service pack to this without a problem. Is it a restriction of Express?

Any ideas?

UPDATE: It has no internet connectivity so I have to do it manually

Comment: Is Express not maintained through windows update?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Microsoft Updates on Windows Updates form it will look for all Microsoft products installed on your server, such as SQL Server. Then, using the automatic download and install settings you'll have SPs installed automatically.